# Why does April O'Neil have so few human friends?

Tags: teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles, april-o-neil

From the first TMNT movie [credits song](https://genius.com/Partnerz-in-kryme-turtle-power-lyrics) (emphasis mine):

> Now our ace reporter was hot on the trail
>   Determined to put these crooks in jail
>   She spied the bad guys and saw what happened
>   But before she knew it, she fell in a trap and got caught!
>   Yeah, she was all alone
>   **With no friends**, and no phone

Now, while this *can* be read that she didn't have any friends with her **in this moment** to help her, after thinking about it, I can't recall April having any human friends other than Casey in any series. While there are a few other human characters scattered throughout the shows--kids, co-workers--April doesn't seem to be *actual friends* with any of them.

There is [this list](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/april-oneil/4005-44968/friends/) that gives examples of April's friends, but the vast majority are either mutants or super-human/super-natural, and the ones that aren't seem to be inconsequential, ie her roommate Trish.

**Why does April have so few human friends? Is this part of her character ever explained?**

Comment: The sign seems pretty explicit. She has no friends to rescue her at that moment (because she can't call them, having had her phone taken), not that she has no friends period.

Comment: And why doesn't she have a phone??

Comment: @user14111 - Have you seen the cost of shellphones?

Comment: why do you need human friends when you can hang out with pizza-eating turtles???

Comment: @user14111 It was 1990. Almost no one had a cellphone. Similarly, almost everyone would quickly forsake their human friends in favor of bipedal reptiles.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recall April having a specific lack of friends. In the 1987 cartoon she has a best friend; Irma the receptionist (and latterly, a reporter) at her news channel.

and in the Archie comics, she's said to be good friends with her roomaate [Oyuki Mamisha](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/oyuki-mamisha/4005-53068/), who also works at her studio as a camerawoman. As with all friendships in movies or comics, this seems to be a case of tail-wag-dog to explain why they're always hanging around together.

---

As to her capacity to *make* friends, the [original character design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_O%27Neil#Portrayal) makes it clear that she's a fierce friend but someone who has an A1 job that requires a lot of her attention.

> There was a very good character description of her, so I looked at
> that and I kind of built her based on me. I felt that she should be a
> very strong character with very good convictions, **she should be a
> loyal friend; she should be serious about her work** and she wanted to
> be taken seriously, not just looked at as another pretty face.

Comment: I'm not sure what your linked video is supposed to show. I don't remember April and Irma being "best friends". Irma looked up to April, sure, but I can't recall them being more than co-workers.

The original design makes sense though, and the quote does pretty much solidify it.

Comment: Video looks dead